# Java -BlockingQueue -- Multiple producers, single consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

Quick clarification please

I know `BlockingQueues` are threadsafe.

Does that mean that I can pass a single reference to a blocking queue to all producers who can  drop Events in willy-nilly to be consumed by a single consumer, and nothing gets disrupted?

Otherwise having to produce up to 20 `BlockingQueues` that may or may not have regular updates and reading them with any efficiency seems an insurmountable task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple blocking queues, single consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588233/multiple-blocking-queues-single-consumer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean that I can pass a single reference to a blocking queue to all producers who can drop Events in willy-nilly to be consumed by a single consumer, and nothing gets disrupted?

In a word, yes. This is safe. To quote the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control.

Comment: Wonderful.  It appears to work, but I didn't want to run into an issue a year from now.

Answer (score 1):

If it's threadsafe that means that you only need one instance of that queue which can be accessed by all threads. The concurrent data structure manages those accesses. **This also means that no synchronization from your side is needed.**

Comment: Thank you very much.  Just wanted to be safe before I committed to this route.  In the past I've always had producer/consumer dyads, but I'm trying to centralize now.

Comment: The concurrent collection seem to be a save way to go for the future as they're also quite performant ;)